# problem with padding from parent to child

Tags: html, css

Here is my codepen : https://codepen.io/jordangio/pen/RwRXJYz

As you can see, I have `padding:0 40px;` set on the main wrapper. Then I use `position:absolute` for the right navigation in order to make it start from right, but as I set `position:relative` to the parent, `right:0` should start exactly from that point where the parent's padding starts.

It turns out that right navigation goes after the parent's content width.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #141414;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 80px;
  width: 50%;
}

.right-navigation {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">


  <div class="left-navigation">
    <div class="right-nav-item">Home</div>
    <div class="right-nav-item">TV Shows</div>
  </div>


  <div class="right-navigation">
    <div class="right-nav-item">Home</div>
    <div class="right-nav-item">TV Shows</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: An element with `position: absolute` with a `top,right,bottom,left` value computes the parent element's padding as part of the parent element. That's why.

Comment: You set the `right` value to the same value as the padding. That's how.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with how it works. It aligns the item to the right of the parent.

You can set margin-left;

```
.right-navigation {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Here is a working snippet;

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  color:white;
}


.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #141414;
    height: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 80px;
    width:50%;
}

.right-navigation {
  margin-left:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  
  
  <div class="left-navigation" >
    <div class="right-nav-item">Home</div>
    <div class="right-nav-item">TV Shows</div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="right-navigation" >
    <div class="right-nav-item">Home</div>
    <div class="right-nav-item">TV Shows</div>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: How does this address OPs issue? I think you're forgetting to also change the position to `relative`.

Comment: This puts the right-navigation div to the right respecting the padding of parent. It solves the problem. No need for position:relative for parent or child.

Comment: Correct, you don't need to add the position - I had forgotten that removing `position: absolute` will set the element to `position: static` which `margin-*: auto` needs in order to work (that or `relative`)

Answer (score 0):

Your child element is absolute, the reason why it's not affected by it's parents padding. If you want to have both left and right navigations to be at the same distance from the edges, then just position them as absolute elements:

```
.right-navigation {
position:absolute;
right:40px;
 }

.left-navigation {
position:absolute;
left:40px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you were using `display: flex` on the parent. There is no need for `position: absolute` here. You can set `justify-content: space-between` on the `.wrapper`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #141414;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 80px;
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">


  <div class="left-navigation">
    <div class="right-nav-item">Home</div>
    <div class="right-nav-item">TV Shows</div>
  </div>


  <div class="right-navigation">
    <div class="right-nav-item">Home</div>
    <div class="right-nav-item">TV Shows</div>
  </div>

</div>
```